# Can Twilio Connect Apps access the connected account's incoming phone numbers?

Tags: twilio

No matter what I try existing phone numbers in a connected account don't show up. Does this mean the connect application must provision all new phone numbers but can't use existing numbers in the user's account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Twilio [Connect](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/connect-overview) account (which is actually a subaccount of the authorizer's account) cannot access the main account phone numbers. So it works as you suspect, in order to send SMS messages from Twilio Connect subaccount you would need to purchase another Twilio phone number.

If you need additional info, I'd suggest reaching out to support via [this form](https://www.twilio.com/help/contact).